# PHP Curl not working as expected

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to make a request in php much like the following request that could be run using the curl command(on linux apt-get install curl):

```
curl -H "X-SOCIALEDGE-ID: 6424a4b2a1b054d78ca1c9c69ca16016" \
    https://api-rc.<the_api_domain>:443/api/publishers?filter=email=<some_email>
```

Which functions giving me a JSON response.

But:

```
class SocialEdgeApi {

    protected $api_key = "6424a4b2a1b054d78ca1c9c69ca16016";
    protected $api_url = "https://api-rc.<the_api_domain>:443/api/";

    private function getBasicCurl($endpoint) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_url.$endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'X-SOCIALEDGE-ID' => $this->api_key
        ]);

        return $ch;
    }

    private function doGetRequest($endpoint) {

        $ch = $this->getBasicCurl($endpoint);

        $head = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($head);
        var_dump($httpCode);
        die();

        return $req;
    }

    public function checkInfluencerExists($email) {
        $http = $this->doGetRequest('publishers?filter=email='.$email);

        die('...'.$resp = $http->getResponseBody());
    }

}
```

And then running in another file or php -a:

```
require_once('SocialEdgeApi.php');
$a = new SocialEdgeApi();
$a->checkInfluencerExists('<some_email>');
```

Returns 403 Forbidden.  That probably means the header was not set correctly.

How can these 2 "curl" requests have different behavior/ what am I missing/doign wrong in the PHP version?

My apologies for not including details that would allow you to test with this particular API, but it's a private 3rd party api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like CURL headers are usually set like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'X-SOCIALEDGE-ID: ' . $this->api_key,
]);
```

Comment: Oh my, what a dumb mistake on my part.  I couldn't see a problem for the life of me.  But of course, everything about php's curl seems archaic in nature (ex. the global functions to assign options), so why would it be cool enough to use an associative array?

Comment: Agreed :) I've made many such mistakes in my time as a developer. In this case however, FWIW I tend to pass over CURL in favor of PHP's native file get/put functions and their stream contexts. Then I'm not relying on an external library to provide functionality that is included in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php if you're not familiar. Just my 2¢

Comment: I was familiar with using the file_get_contents to make a get request; but I will later have to make post requests with a post body, would those solutions still be suitable for that?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You would be looking to use the ```content``` option. Documentation for the HTTP-specific context options are at http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: I +1'd your comments and added them as a separate answer for reader convenience because I think that is something that they should consider.

Answer (score 1):

As EVILoptimist noted one good alternative to curl would be PHP's stream contexts.  I'm describing that here for the convenience of those whom stumble across this.

You can simply perform a get request like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

For post requests see the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.example-post